# Selecting a JSTL tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tags, frontend

I am trying to query a selector that is wrapped inside a JSTL tag. So far no luck yet. Did anyone face this problem before?

when i try to select the homepage banner on this site for example: https://www.teknosa.com/

using the following code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('body > div.wrapper > section > div > fmt:setlocale > div.main-slider.desktop.hidden-xs > div > div')
```

I get a 'not valid selector' as a response. The fmt:setlocale selector that is wrapping up the page is messing things up.

Thanks. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
document.querySelector('body .wrapper section div .main-slider div div');
```

This selector will return the `<div class="slick-list draggable">` element as a result.

When "querySelectorAll" is used, all elements are returned as a result. There are many results in the code you want to select when you get here "body .wrapper section div" and you have to choose which result you want to continue with.
When "querySelector" is used, only the first result of the sheet is taken

This code will return the same result but use "querySelectorAll"

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('body .wrapper section div');
var y = x[0].querySelectorAll('.main-slider div div')[0];
```

Comment: Its working :) thank you very much.. can you explain how it works? and why when i copy a selector and paste it in the document.queryselector function it doesnt work

Comment: I edited my post by writing a description